# passing splice instructions

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns, optional-arguments

Consider some passing splice instructions using `start,stop,step` pattern

```
r`data = Range@10;
r`f[data_, start_: 1, stop_: - 1, every_: 1] :=
 Module[{},
  data[[start ;; stop ;; every]] 
 ]
```

1. Is there a performance penalty if the splice is effectively a non-splice i.e. `[[1;;-1;;1]]` or `[[1;;;;1]]` or `[[;;Length@data;;]]` etc compared to say returning `data`? The reason I ask is if so, must I specifically skip splicing in such casses?
2. Consider the case when multiple splice instrcutions have to be passed: `start1,stop1,step1`, `start2,stop2,step2`.... How to structure this compactly in func arguments? e.g. is there something better than `` r`f[data_, splice1_:{-1,1,1},...] ``

Comment: Why not just pass `start ;; stop ;; every` directly? The fullform of this is `Span[start, stop, every]`, so that should also make it easy to put multiple `Span`s in a list. As for your other question: `Part` is highly optimized, so I doubt that there's much point in trying to work around specific cases.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit sry...didn't understand...how exactly do I pass `start;;stop;;every` in r'f? Did you mean something like `r'f[...,start;;stop;;every]:=...`

Comment: You can just do something like `f[data_List, span_Span]  := data[[span]]` and then call it as, e.g.,  `f[Range[5], 1;;3]`.

Answer (score 1):

### First question - performance penalty:

I use `Range` to create sample data and timed the evaluation of all these forms which in the end produce exact same results on AMD Ryzen 1700 with Mathematica 12.2:

```
data[[1 ;; Length@data ;; 1]]   (* "1;L;1" *)
data[[1 ;; Length@data]]        (* "1;L" *)
data[[1 ;; -1 ;; 1]]            (* "1;-1;1" *)
data[[1 ;; -1]]                 (* "1;-1" *)
data[[All]]                     (* "All" *)
data                            (* "Plain" *)
```

Here you can see the effect of array size with fixed number of evaluation in the forms:

[image]

This figure shows the effect of times the form evaluated with fixed size array in the forms:

[image]

keep in mind that after running the code multiple times, I see slightly different results in `Span` forms.

As shown in both figures, `plain` form is faster than other form.
With 10,000 evluation on an Array with size of 10,000, `Plain` is over 150 times faster than the slowest one, so

Is there a penalty? `Definitely Yes`.
How much? depends on the array size.

The `All` Form has some mixed results, on arrays with low number of elements, it's slower than other forms but on arrays with large number of elements, it will do the job faster than any `Span` form but slower than the `Plain`.

In measuring different forms, I didn't measure memory usage but base on evaluation times, I think we will have some penalty with memory too.

Code:

```
f[x_, i_ : 10000] := Module[{data},
  data = Range[x];
  Return[{
    AbsoluteTiming[Do[data[[1 ;; Length@data ;; 1]];, i];][[1]],
    AbsoluteTiming[Do[data[[1 ;; Length@data]];, i];][[1]],
    AbsoluteTiming[Do[data[[1 ;; -1 ;; 1]];, i];][[1]],
    AbsoluteTiming[Do[data[[1 ;; -1]];, i];][[1]],
    AbsoluteTiming[Do[data[[All]];, i];][[1]],
    AbsoluteTiming[Do[data;, i];][[1]]
    }]
  ]

ListPlot[Transpose@Table[f[i], {i, {10000, 25000, 50000, 100000}}],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotLabels -> {"1;L;1", "1;L", "1;-1;1", "1;-1", "All", "Plain"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Number of evaluation = 10,000",
 AxesLabel -> {"Array Size", "Timing (s)"},
 Ticks -> {{{1, 10000}, {2, 25000}, {3, 50000}, {4, 100000}}, Automatic}]


ListPlot[Transpose@Table[f[10000, i], {i, {10000, 25000, 50000, 100000}}],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotLabels -> {"1;L;1", "1;L", "1;-1;1", "1;-1", "All", "Plain"},
 PlotLabel -> "Array size = 10,000",
 AxesLabel -> {"N. of evaluation", "Timing (s)"},
 Ticks -> {{{1, 10000}, {2, 25000}, {3, 50000}, {4, 100000}}, Automatic}]
```

### Second question - a function to apply multiple span on data:

```
f[data_, spans__] := Fold[#1[[#2]] &, data, List[spans]]
```

First you specify data and the rest of argument (whether is one or two or ...) will be used as span and will apply in order of `data[[arg2]][[arg3]][[...]]`

You can use it in different forms:

```
f[{1, 2, 3, 4}, Span[1, 3], Span[2, 3]]
(*or*)
f[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 1 ;; 3, 2 ;; 3]
```

Output:

```
{2, 3}
```